# Tian third moment-matching tree with smoothing - implementation

Tags: options, option-pricing

I was wondering if someone has an implementation of the Tian third moment-matching tree (http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1030143) with
smoothing in code (e.g. c++, vba, c#, etc.)?
It would help hugely if the implementation also shows how to handle discrete dividends and calculate greeks (delta, vega, gamma, theta, rho).